# React Native: _chalk.constructor is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, react-native

I just wanted to share an issue that took me 1h to debug.

After isolating a functional component in a separate file I had this error appear in metro:

```
TypeError: _chalk.constructor is not a constructor 
at getChalk (/Users/.../node_modules/@babel/highlight/lib/index.js:102:31)
    at codeFrameColumns (/Users/.../node_modules/@babel/code-frame/lib/index.js:88:41)
```

The trace was quite misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that by moving my functional component, one image path was now wrong in a ImageBackground component and caused the crash.

```
<ImageBackground
      source={require("../../images/background_splash.png")}
```